# How to escape \\ after reading it using JSTL

Tags: java, regex, jstl

I have following regular expression in JSP

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s!&%()+:'.\/\\-]*$
```

When i am reading this using `JSTL` it becomes

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s!&%()+:'.\/\-]*$
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i get `\\\` after reading using `JSTl`. I think this is getting escaped.

Comment: Just use four slashes - `\\\\ `

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use four slashes:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s!&%()+:'.\/\\\\-]*$
```